# Is there a Free Software common managment console for different hypervisors (Proxmox and VMware)?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, kvm, self-hosting, proxmox

Good afternoon, colleagues!
Faced with a new task for me - it is required to combine two types of hypervisors under one management console. I want to create, delete, clone and do other manipulation with VMs from the common management console. This console must be a free or open source.
Our hypervisors are VMware and Proxmox.
Maybe someone faced such a challenge - I ask for your advice.
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is to add a cloud manager on top of your hypervisors. OpenStack was created with some of this in mind

With OpenStack you can manage varied hypervisor technologies in one place. OpenStack is a bit of a beast to setup though.

You might want to start with [this video](https://www.openstack.org/videos/summits/boston-2017/vmware-openstack-and-vmware-enterprise-grade-iaas-built-on-proven-foundation) which goes over the advantages of a VMWare + OpenStack deployment.